# Java - Spring data access object implementation

Tags: java, spring, interface, dao, implementation

In my current spring setup i would like to implement a slightly different architecture, here is my setup:

I have a "base" DAO interface, which lists all CRUD operations:

```
public interface BaseDao {

    public boolean create(Object obj);

    public List<Object> read();

    public boolean update(Object obj);

    public boolean delete(Object obj);

}
```

Next i have "specific" DAO interface, which extends from the "base" one:

```
public interface ArticleDao extends BaseDao {

    public List<Article> getArticlesByAttribute(String attribute);

}
```

And finally, the Repository, which implements the interface:

```
public class ArticleDaoImpl implements ArticleDao {

    public boolean create(Article article) {
        // code
    }

    public List<Article> read() {
        // code
    }

    public boolean update(Article article) {
        // code
    }

    public boolean delete(Article article) {
        // code
    }

    public List<Article> getArticlesByAttribute(String attribute) {
        // code
    }
}
```

So the idea is simple:

I want every Repository to implement all crud operations + "the methods from the specific dao-interface"

But i get the following error:

```
ArticleDaoImpl is not abstract and does not override
abstract method delete(java.lang.Object) in BaseDao
```

etc..

So this is probably because i defined Object as a parameter in the interface and "Article" as a parameter in the actual implementation..

Anybody got the idea how i can follow this pattern correctly?
Should i consider working with generics?

Thanks and Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should work with Spring Data JPA/MongoDB etc. It will make MOST of your boilerplate code go away. Seriously - forget about DAO and go with Spring Data JPA: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: mhm, but what about hibernate, how can i integrate it in this context? i mean, i installed hibernate just for querying/saving data, do i even need it now?

Comment: It would be best to just follow Spring Data JPA turorial (which uses Hibernate) for a complete but clear Hibernate configuration. If you are using Spring Boot then it will be a breeze. Check out this example: https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate

Comment: hey, yea you are right, but just in case... could you refer how to implement my question above? use of generics?